# Yii, i need help creating a CRUD for a Module

Tags: php, yii, module

I have already tried this in Gii, My module uses its own db
 
 
  [image: crud in Gii] 
When i preview i get CException *Property "GiiModule.db" is not defined.* 
Main App config **../config/main.php**, I included my module and its db connection

```
modules=>(
     'booksImported'=>array(
     'db'=>array(
     'connectionString'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbimports',
     'username' => 'root',
     'password' => 'unl0ck',
     'class'=>'CDbConnection'
        )
  )
```

My module **..protected\modules\booksImported\BooksImportedModule.php**

```
class BooksImportedModule extends CWebModule
 {
   public $db
   public function init()
   ...
}
```

My model **...\protected\modules\booksImported\models\Importedbooks.php**

```
class Importedbooks extends CActiveRecord
 {
   ...
   public function getDbConnection()
   {
    $db = Yii::app()->controller->module->db;  
    return Yii::createComponent($db);
   }
 }
```

I have managed to create a CRUD for modules that uses the same db as main App, i'm js struggling with this one. Please help

Comment: Your problem is that your module if it uses different database creates problem right.???

Comment: Note really, because i managed to create a Model inside this Module from  its db(diff from main db), m js  facing a problem a problem with CRUD for this module

Comment: I guess in your getDbConnection() function you just need to return the db connection name just like 
return Yii::app()->controller->module->db;

Comment: Ok i c, bt how cn i do that Sir..cn u edit my getDbConnection() code

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Steps to create curd operation in yii

1)first you need create model generate

Click model generator and put table name in table name text box and it load model id in below textbox. Copy.Copy that model id and click following buttons first preview and generate.

2)Second you need create curd generate
    Click curd generator and paste model id in model name textbox and it load controller id and click following buttons first preview and generate.

Now run following url like :`www.yourserver.com/index.php?r=controllername/create`

Comment: I knw how to create a CRUD on the main App, my problem is creating it in a Module that uses a diff db..u  js  gave steps on hw to create a CRUD, nothing difficult thr

Answer (score 0):

Just return the db in getDbConnection function

```
class Importedbooks extends CActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public function getDbConnection()
    {
        return Yii::app()->controller->module->db;
    }
}
```

I hope this will solve your error.